# TikZ picture not rendering in different environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, texmaker, tikz-arrows, rstudio

I successfully constructed a TikZ diagram with the following code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, positioning, arrows, shapes}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{rectangle state/.style={draw,rectangle}} % make rectangles available
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[state, minimum size=1.5cm] (y1) {$\mathbf{y}_{1}$};
  \node[rectangle state,minimum size=1.5cm] (x11) [below= of y1] {$x_{11}$};
  \node[rectangle state,minimum size=1.5cm] (x21) [below= of x11] {$\mathbf{x}_{21}$};
  \node[rectangle state, minimum size=1.5cm] (x31) [below= of x21] {$\mathbf{x}_{31}$};
  \node[state, minimum size=1.5cm] (y2) [right= of y1] {$\mathbf{y}_{2}$};
  \node[rectangle state, minimum size=1.5cm] (x12) [right= of x11] {$x_{12}$};
  \node[rectangle state, minimum size=1.5cm] (x22) [right= of x21] {$\mathbf{x}_{22}$};
  \node[rectangle state, minimum size=1.5cm] (x32) [right= of x31] {$\mathbf{x}_{32}$};
  \node[state, draw=none, minimum size=1.5cm] (ykdots) [right= of y2] {$\cdots$};
  \node[state, draw=none, minimum size=1.5cm] (x1kdots) [right= of x12] {$\cdots$};
  \node[state, draw=none, minimum size=1.5cm] (x2kdots) [right= of x22] {$\cdots$};
  \node[state, draw=none, minimum size=1.5cm] (x3kdots) [right= of x32] {$\cdots$};
  \node[state, minimum size=1.5cm] (ynm1) [right= of ykdots] {$\mathbf{y}_{n-1}$};
  \node[rectangle state, minimum size=1.5cm] (x1nm1) [below= of ynm1] {$x_{1,n-1}$};
  \node[rectangle state, minimum size=1.5cm] (x2nm1) [below= of x1nm1] {$\mathbf{x}_{2,n-1}$};
  \node[rectangle state, minimum size=1.5cm] (x3nm1) [below= of x2nm1] {$\mathbf{x}_{3,n-1}$};
  \node[state, minimum size=1.5cm] (yn) [right= of ynm1] {$\mathbf{y}_{n}$};
  \node[rectangle state, minimum size=1.5cm] (x1n) [below= of yn] {$x_{1n}$};
  \node[rectangle state, minimum size=1.5cm] (x2n) [below= of x1n] {$\mathbf{x}_{2n}$};
  \node[rectangle state, minimum size=1.5cm] (x3n) [below= of x2n] {$\mathbf{x}_{3n}$};
  \draw[->] 
    (x11) edge[left] (y1)
    (x21) edge[bend left] (y1)
    (x31) edge[bend left] (y1)
    (x12) edge[left] (y2)
    (x22) edge[bend left] (y2)
    (x32) edge[bend left] (y2)
    (x1nm1) edge[left] (ynm1)
    (x2nm1) edge[bend left] (ynm1)
    (x3nm1) edge[bend left] (ynm1)
    (x1n) edge[left] (yn)
    (x2n) edge[bend left] (yn)
    (x3n) edge[bend left] (yn)
    (x11) edge[left] (x12)
    (x21) edge[left] (x22)
    (x31) edge[left] (x32)
    (x12) edge[left] (x1kdots)
    (x22) edge[left] (x2kdots)
    (x32) edge[left] (x3kdots)
    (x1kdots) edge[left] (x1nm1)
    (x2kdots) edge[left] (x2nm1)
    (x3kdots) edge[left] (x3nm1)
    (x1nm1) edge[left] (x1n)
    (x2nm1) edge[left] (x2n)
    (x3nm1) edge[left] (x3n)
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

and it looks fine:

[image: correct image]

However, when I drop that code in verbatim into a draft of a paper I'm writing, it looks like this:

[image: bad picture]

The alignment is wrong, the nodes don't have borders drawn anymore, etc. Anybody know what's going on? Do any of the following packages in my preamble mess up TikZ stuff? The successful compilation was performed on `Rstudio`, and the unsuccessful compilation took place on `Texmaker`. With the latter, I compile by pressing F1, which triggers "Quick Build" and the settings of that are displayed in the pictures at the bottom. I use XeLateX because I've had some problems in the past with images (pdf mostly) being displayed properly. The "XeLateX" command is given as `xelatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, bm, mathtools, algpseudocode, amssymb}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{psfrag,epsf,algorithm}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{url} % not crucial - just used below for the URL

% tikz stuff
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, positioning, arrows, shapes}


%\pdfminorversion=4
% NOTE: To produce blinded version, replace "0" with "1" below.
\newcommand{\blind}{0}

% for proofs!
\newenvironment{proof}{\paragraph{Proof:}}{\hfill$\square$}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[theorem]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

% DON'T change margins - should be 1 inch all around.
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-.5in}%
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-.5in}%
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1in}%
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.3in}%
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.8in}%


\begin{document}
```

[image: Quick Build Settings]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE! How do you compile your draft? That is, which compilation chain are you using? The fact that you are loading `psfrag` and `epsf` seems to indicate that you run `latex`, convert to `ps` and then to pdf. The details of this chain may be important for understanding what's going on. (And do you need `psfrag` and `epsf` in the year 2019?)

Comment: this is unrelated to texmaker (or rstudio) but rather to which tex system you used, latex or pdflatex and the versions of packages involved.

Comment: I suppose that you are viewing the dvi output, which doesn't really make sense. View the pdf output.

Comment: @marmot see edit. Regarding `psfrag` and `epsf`, those were just part of the journal's template they distribute.

Comment: You seem to be compiling with `xelatex` (which may not be optimal, but if the journal forces you, what can you do) but the second picture doesn't show which system commands your program associates with `xelatex`. Maybe you should really double check it runs `xelatex`. I always compile from the console so I can't say much.

Comment: @marmot the display got cut off so I copy-pasted it in the text above: `xelatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex` By the way, I took a look at the `.ps` file generated and it seems to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed `\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}` and now it works. I tried a few other things as well, in addition to the things that were suggested in the comments, and those didn't really pan out.